# R Function to automate analyses over a list of permutated variables

Tags: r, function, regression

I'm looking for a function to automate a simple mediation analysis over a list of possible permutations.

The real life problem is this: I have data from 5 questionnaires and I'd like to run an exploratory simple mediation for every possible combination of 3 variables (questionnaires). So that each of the 5 is used as an `outcome (Y)`, `predictor (X)` and `mediator (M)`. That gives a total of 60 mediations.

*I'm fully aware that's something methodologically wrong. Nevertheless I'd still like to try*

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(gtools)

### Generate data for 5 questionnaire (in wide format)     
matrix <- replicate(5,rnorm(100))
df<- as.data.frame(matrix)

### Generate a vector with questionnaire names
variables <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")

### Save all 3 element permutations out of 5 questionnaires and set their column names for mediation
prmtns <- permutations(n=5, r=3, v=variables, repeats.allowed = FALSE)
colnames(prmtns) <- c("Y", "X", "M")
```

Now that we have some exemplary data,
a regular mediation analysis using `mediation` package *would* follow these steps (note, that there is no `data` dataframe. Our data resides in `df` and this is just an example of steps):

```
require(mediation)

model.M <- lm(M ~ X, data)
model.Y <- lm(Y ~ X + M, data)
results.y.x.m <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='X', mediator='M',
                   boot=TRUE, sims=100)
summary(results.y.x.m)
```

**My** big **question is**, how can I make `R` to iterate / automate these analyses with `df` database over all possible combinations of what `Y`, `X` and `M` could be (permutations are already saved in `prmtns` matrix):

```
> head(prmtns)
     Y    X    M   
[1,] "V1" "V2" "V3"
[2,] "V1" "V2" "V4"
[3,] "V1" "V2" "V5"
[4,] "V1" "V3" "V2"
[5,] "V1" "V3" "V4"
[6,] "V1" "V3" "V5"
```

So that, 1st analysis will use (as per row:1) specific variables from `df` dataframe

`V1` as `Y`, `V2` as `X` and `V3` as `M`.

2nd analysis will use the next permutation (as saved in 2nd row of`prmtns`):

`V1` as `Y`, `V2` as `X` and `V4` as `M` and so on.

An explicit example using previously generated data would be:

```
#1 iteration over `prmtns`(see rows of head(prmtns) above)

model.M <- lm(V3 ~ V2, df)
model.Y <- lm(V1 ~ V2 + V3, df)
results.v1.v2.v3 <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='V2', mediator='V3',
                   boot=TRUE, sims=100)
summary(results.v1.v2.v3)

#2 iteration over `prmtns` 

model.M <- lm(V4 ~ V2, df)
model.Y <- lm(V1 ~ V2 + V4, df)
results.v1.v2.v4 <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='V2', mediator='V3',
                   boot=TRUE, sims=100)
summary(results.v1.v2.v4)
```

Saving `results.y.x.m` with a unique name based on actual variables would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that will perform the mediation and then map over it using `purrr::pmap_df()`. In order to save the input variables, you can put them in a tibble and utilize the list-column feature to save the summary.

```
perm_med <- function(Y, X, M) {
  fm_m <- as.formula(paste(M, "~", X))
  fm_y <- as.formula(paste(Y, "~", paste(c(X, M), collapse = "+")))
  model.M <- lm(fm_m, df)
  model.Y <- lm(fm_y, df)
  results.y.x.m <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat=X, mediator=M,
                          boot=TRUE, sims=100)
  tibble::tibble(y = Y, x = X, m = M, results = list(summary(results.y.x.m)))
}
results <- purrr::pmap_df(list(prmtns[, 1], prmtns[, 2], prmtns[, 3]), perm_med)
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I think this won't work. `Y`, `X` and `M` are column names in the `prmtns` matrix. Analysis should run on `df` data frame where, according to each row of `prmtns` `Y` could be `V1`, `X` could be `V2` and `M` could be `V3`. Those `V1:V5` variables is where the actual data is. PS. I edited my question so that it's hopefully more clear.

Comment: hmm I think this works in the case that `Y`, `X`, and `M` are column names (I've reproduced it like this: `data <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(10), X = rnorm(10), rnorm(10))` and then used the function above and `prmtns ` as suggested above.) It is possible I'm missing something though.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that's not the case. There are a total of 5 variables `V1` to `V5` saved in `df` dataframe. `Y`, `X` and `M` are just containers that use different permutations of 3 out of 5 `V's`. If you don't mind have a look at "explicit example" I just added to the end of my question. Sorry for being imprecise.

Comment: i'll try to put it in a different way, maybe it will help. I want to run a total of 60 analysis. Why 60? Because there are 60 possible permutations of 3 unique elements taken from a set of 5. These 5 are my variables: `V1` to `V5`. I want to run as many mediation analysis (using 3 variables) as there are permutations so that each variable is used as an `outcome` (Y), `predictor` (X) and `mediator` (M). Exemplary data is saved in `df` dataframe.

Comment: considering the above, function that I need should 1st look into `prmtns` matrix to see which variables from `dt` use as `Y`, `X` and `M` arguments in a typical mediation and iterate over all row of `prmtns` computing all possible mediations

Comment: Ah okay, I've updated the function above to reflect what (I think) you've explained. This seems to work with `data <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(10), V2 = rnorm(10), V3 = rnorm(10), V4 = rnorm(10), V5 = rnrom(10))` 

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for! Now I need to figure out how to add to `results` names of variables used for each mediation. Currently there is no trace of what's beeing mediated. Also there is a type in your comment: `V5 = rnrom(10))`.